# *ngIf behaviour: how to conditionally show data in angular 2?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

Here is the show-data component:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'show-data',
    template: `yes! Now showing the show-data directive template !`
})
export class ShowData {}
```

And its parent:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `
The 'shouldShow' boolean value is: {{shouldShow}}
<show-data *ngIf="shouldShow"></show-data>
<div *ngIf="!shouldShow">NOT showing the show-data directive template</div>
`,
    directives: [ShowData]
})
export class App {
    shouldShow:boolean = false;
    constructor(){
        console.log("shouldShow value before timeout",this.shouldShow);
        window.setTimeout(function(){
            this.shouldShow = true;
            console.log("shouldShow value after timeout",this.shouldShow);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Initially, the `shouldShow` variable is set to false, and the `show-data` directive template does not show. Fine.

`shouldShow` is then set to 'true' after one second, by the parent component constructor.

Why isn't the value of `shouldShow` updated in the parent component view?

Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/a8UBQ76Af0YUFjreXuLX?p=preview)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem is not on the `*ngIf` itself. it's on `setTimeout(function(){...})` because `this` inside the anonymous function will refer to the function itself not to the `AppComponent` instance.

So,instead, to be able to access the `AppComponent` instance. Use [**lambda expression**](https://chrisrng.svbtle.com/es6-lambda-expressions)(also termed as Arrow functions).

Here is your [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/A8FudS9CgbBzHrlM1Bbh?p=preview) edited

```
window.setTimeout(()=>{
   this.shoulShow = true;
   console.log("shoulShow value after timeout",this.shoulShow);
}, 1000);
```

Alternatively, you can assign `this` to a new variable to be able to access it from inside the anonymous function.

```
let that = this
window.setTimeout(function(){
   that.shoulShow = true; // here use the new var 'that' instead of 'this'
   console.log("shoulShow value after timeout",that.shoulShow);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: You beat me to it :D

Comment: @CosminAbabei  You will get the next one ;)

Comment: I noticed that,  in the console, "shoulShow value after timeout",this.shoulShow still returns 'false' (even though it is 'true' in the view) whereas 'that.shoulShow' correctly returns 'true' (second solution you mentioned). Any idea why?

Comment: @Manube is it `this.shoulShow` in the console.log(...) ? because it should be `that.shoulShow`

Comment: with the lambda notation, after the value of 'shoulShow' is changed to 'true', it still returns 'false' in the console callback; that does not seem to happen when using the this/that trick. I updated the plunker with your first solution, you can check the console: http://plnkr.co/edit/a8UBQ76Af0YUFjreXuLX?p=preview

Comment: @Manube in the plunker you made, you forgot to put a { , in `window.setTimeout(()=>` it should've been `window.setTimeout(()=>{` , I have to say, it missed with my head for a moment :)